# DAAD funding for stay abroad for PhD students and postdocs: is it added to the regular TV-L salary?

Tags: funding, germany, early-career, administration, travel

There are several funding options from the German DAAD for PhD students and Postdoc working in German universities to visit other countries:

- [Research grants for doctoral candidates](https://www2.daad.de/ausland/studieren/stipendium/de/70-stipendien-finden-und-bewerben/?status=4&target=&subjectGrps=C&intention=2&daad=1&q=&page=NaN&detail=57556279)
- [Research grants for young researchers with a doctorate (postdoc program) - short grants](https://www2.daad.de/ausland/studieren/stipendium/de/70-stipendien-finden-und-bewerben/?status=2&target=&subjectGrps=C&intention=2&daad=1&q=&page=1&detail=57243862)
- [PRIME Postdoctoral Researchers International Mobility Experience](https://www2.daad.de/ausland/studieren/stipendium/de/70-stipendien-finden-und-bewerben/?status=2&target=&subjectGrps=C&intention=2&daad=1&q=&page=1&detail=57092234)

**Question:** Are these funds added to the regular TV-L salary that the postdocs or PhD students receive from their own university? Or do they replace such salary for the duration of the stay abroad?

Comment: I think I have a pretty solid idea what the answer is but I would strongly encourage you to contact the DAAD and ask them directly.

Comment: How much is it (compared to, say, 50% TVL)? That might give a hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is found in https://www.daad.de/de/im-ausland-studieren-forschen-lehren/stipendien-finanzierung/wichtige-hinweise-zu-daad-stipendien/, Section E, Point 4:

> If you are receiving a salary as a PhD student, the "domestic part" of the stipend - currently 850 EUR - is substracted from your DAAD stipend.

Note that there is a direct link to that site (explicitly referring to Section E, for precisely such kind of questions you ask) from the 1st page you link to.