# How long after DFG grant to start work

Tags: postdocs, funding, germany

One way in Germany to get money for academic research is to apply for grants at the German Research Foundation called DFG. The DFG provides information on numerous things through documents. If you apply for your own position as a temporary principal investigator Eigene Stelle, the review process takes around 6 to 7 months.

What I was not able to find any information on was how long it takes to start work after you got a DFG grant. If the DFG tells me on 01.01. that I got the grant, how long would it take until I can start work and get paid from that grant?

This

[How do the logistics work for recipients of a DFG "Eigene Stelle" grant (in Germany)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175223/how-do-the-logistics-work-for-recipients-of-a-dfg-eigene-stelle-grant-in-germ)

describes some of the technicalities after you get a grant, but does not mention anything about how long all that takes.

Comment: Just one piece of advice: Give the DFG a call. Your contact person should be mentioned in the letter that you got the grant. They will be able to answer this question and any other question you may have instantaneously. The DFG contact persons are usually very supportive.

Comment: @Snijderfrey I don't get the sense that OP actually has gotten a grant like this, but are intending to plan ahead; this is quite important if one is trying to be funded continuously without gaps.

Comment: @BryanKrause, you might be right. BureucracyIsAWasteOfTime, would you clarify?

Comment: I think the bottleneck isn't the DFG but the host Institution. They might need a few weeks to prepare your employment contract(s) etc.

Comment: At my university in Germany they are so understaffed in the human resources department that it can take not weeks but months at the moment to get someone employed.

Comment: I have got a DFG grant application in process, but depending on how long it takes between the DFG telling me I got or did not get it and actually working, I would now apply for something. If it is just a few weeks, I do not have to apply for anything else. If it is a few months, an application somewhere is advisable.

Comment: @BureucracyIsAWasteOfTime What will you do if your application is not successful?

Comment: I do not compute. I did not even know those words could be used like this in a sentence. I have a non academic job I can always do, but that is not ideal. Additionally there is a 6 month academic position I was advised to apply for, where the application is mostly a formality, but it is not well funded. The DFG should inform me soon about the grant. Consequently, I have to decide soon whether to apply for that position or not. If I already know now that it takes months to actually start work, I'd probably take that 6 month position. If it only takes weeks, there is no need.